# I want to get words (token) from string in typescripts starts with $

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

As below example I want to get tokens from string using typescript:

```
var str = "Hello $FirstName $LastName, Your account with number $AccountNumber will activate soon".
```

Expected result :

An array: `["$FirstName","$LastName","$AccountNumber"]`

Or comma separated string: `var commaSepData = "$FirstName,$LastName,$AccountNumber";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
var str = "Hello $FirstName $LastName, Your account with number $AccountNumber will activate soon";

res = str.split(' ').filter( chunk => chunk.includes('$'))

//res = ["$FirstName", "$LastName,", "$AccountNumber"]
```

Comment: Thanks, Its helpful to me

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use a regexp:

```js
const str = "Hello $FirstName $LastName, Your account with number $AccountNumber will activate soon";
const groups = str.match(/(\$\w+)/g);
console.log(groups);
```